# Ask for password before uninstalling application

Tags: android, service, uninstallation

First of all, I have researched a lot about my issue, but I could not find a proper solution so I am posting my query here. Hope to get a better solution to the issue:

I have a requirement where I need to ask for password to the user before user deletes my app from settings or from any other application like MyAppSharer. I have found one solution where I can successfully be able to call my activity when user clicks on Uninstall button. I have applied trick here, and calling service. In service, I run timer which runs every 1 second and in that one second, it checks for top most activity of running task. This is running perfectly as per expected.

Now, my issue is, this activity apppears on each of application user tries to uninstall. I need that the activity which I call, should only appear for my application when user tries to uninstall my application.

Here is my code:

```
public static final String PACKAGE_INSTALLER = "com.android.packageinstaller";
public static final String PACKAGE_INSTALLER_UNINSTALL_ACTIVITY = "com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity";


alarmTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);;
            ComponentName topActivity = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;

            final String packageName = topActivity.getPackageName();
            String className = topActivity.getClassName();

            Log.v(TAG, "packageName:" + packageName);
            Log.v(TAG, "className:" + className);

            if (PACKAGE_INSTALLER.equals(packageName)
                && PACKAGE_INSTALLER_UNINSTALL_ACTIVITY.equals(className)) {

                //Here I need to apply one condition where package name received to be matched with my package name. But I am not sure how to fetch package name of selected application for uninstalling 
                //To Cancel Existing UninstallerActivity and redirect user to home.
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent();
                homeIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startActivity(homeIntent);

                //To open my activity
                    Intent loginActivity = new Intent(UninstallService.this, Act_Login.class);
                    loginActivity.putExtra(Constants.KEY_IS_FROM_SERVICE, true);
                    loginActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(loginActivity); 

            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: I am not sure about your intention behind it but from a users point of view, I will not like an app which will ask for things when I am un-installing it. The very fact that I am un-installing the app means either I am not happy with it or I have a better option or may be something else. Whatever may be the reason, asking for something at this point of time may further annoy me. So be careful about it. I hope your intentions are good.

Comment: @AtulOHolic I think they are trying to make a virus ? :)

Comment: did you log the package name and find out if the way you are getting the package name is correct or not ?

Comment: I'd just delete the apk file from the device to get around your strange check. Or I'd just run `pm disable` on your service and then uninstall.

Comment: To ask for password before uninstalling an app is a bad practice

Comment: did you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/2683275)?

Answer (score 5):

you should try something like the following :

1st - declare your broadcast recevier in the Manifest file , that will listen to  QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART :

```
  <receiver android:name=".UninstallReceiver">
          <intent-filter android:priority="999999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
          </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

2nd - your UnunstallIntentReceiver java class like the following :

```
public class UninstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // fetching package names from extras
        String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES"); 

        if(packageNames!=null){
            for(String packageName: packageNames){
                if(packageName!=null && packageName.equals("application_package")){
                   // start your activity here and ask the user for the password 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

and please give me some feedback

Hope That Helps.

Comment: This one works fine with 2.3 but doesn't work with 4.x

Comment: It's not work in 6.0 or above, is there any permission required?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a corporate requirement (if you want to block a regular user from uninstalling your app, no chance, thanks Google for protecting us from bad devs), you should create a device administrator application. This way, although the user still can delete the app, it's one extra step if you want to prevent accidental erasing.

Before deleting your app, if it's enabled as device admin, the user must first disable the app as administrator, and the app receives this broadcast.

In your XML, put

```
<activity android:name=".app.DeviceAdminSample"
            android:label="@string/activity_sample_device_admin">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name=".app.DeviceAdminSample$DeviceAdminSampleReceiver"
        android:label="@string/sample_device_admin"
        android:description="@string/sample_device_admin_description"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the receiver, you have at least two methods worth noticing:

```
@Override
public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
    …
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    …
}
```

This way you know the user is potentially going to erase your app.

Complete guide for device administration is at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing code for device admin. If you install MyAppSharer and click on the application in which device admin will be enabled, it will automatically open device admin to deactivate, and if user deactivates, you can uninstall application. I need that user cannot be able to uninstall until they have their password remembered and entered.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root permissions make your app system (remove your apk-file from `/data` to `/system` directories). Then reboot device. After reboot your app is not available to delete by user (not superuser).

Answer (score 1):

The only way i see, is to provide your own uninstaller as part of your app (= an activity that lists all apps and allows to uninstall them). Your service could then check if your app was the one that started the packageinstaller and if not redirect the user.

It is not possible (at least on the Android 4.4 I tested with) to grab the uninstaller activity data without root or being a system app. This is because the uninstaller is not called as an independent task, but as an activity on the stack of the starting task (which is the Settings app when uninstalling from settings, etc). You can only see the Task details of the calling task.

However there might be some really dirty possibility left, that i didn't test to the end: You could register the hidden interface `IThumbnailReceiver` [1] with the hidden three argument version of `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks` [2]. It seems like only the GET_TASKS permission is needed to grab a thumbnail (see [3]). It should be possible to find out which app is going to be removed from the app thumbnail... - But as this solution uses hidden APIs, there is no guarantee that it will work with older/newer/vendored Android versions.

1. https://github.com/omnirom/android_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.4/core/java/android/app/IThumbnailReceiver.aidl
2. https://github.com/omnirom/android_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.4/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java#L766
3. https://github.com/omnirom/android_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.4/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#L6725