# How to kill system uninstaller activity

Tags: android, system, kill-process

I'm trying to stop "com.android.uninstaller.UnistallerActivity" when appeared 
i use following code:

```
public static void killThisPackageIfRunning(final Context context, String packageName){
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
    }
```

and call it like that:

```
killThisPackageIfRunning(getApplicationContext(),"com.android.uninstaller.UnistallerActivity");
// and
killThisPackageIfRunning(getApplicationContext(),"com.android.uninstaller");
```

but doesn't work! i'm doing something wrong? or it's not the best way to do that?

I get  *Invalid packageName: com.android.uninstaller.UnistallerActivity* error!
is there another name for uninstaller activity, or because it's an activity and `killBackgroundProcesses` don't kill activities?

i know there another way to kill apps:

```
Process.sendSignal(pid, Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
```

but does it gd solution to stop system activity? how to know pid of UnistallerActivity if it's started?

i know it's not something simple but is there a hack (things of superuser permission to do that?)

any indication / idea / discussion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a legitimate reason to prevent a user from uninstalling an app?

Comment: Yes, its work app installed in work phone. if you work already on work PC you don't have to uninstall any app i guess!

Comment: Then use permissions. Killing the uninstaller might cause unpleasantness,

Comment: Yess, i use the required permission, i know abt unpleasantness thing but that's professional app not for public use, we gonna lose lot of valuable data if the app uninstalled, especially it's used by many employees!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the packageName to kill the process.

`com.android.uninstaller.UnistallerActivity` is not a valid packageName, it doesn't exist. The packageName is `com.android.packageinstaller` and the Acitivity name (though not needed or useful to kill an app) is `com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity`.

Note that `killBackgroundProcesses` can only be used to kill processes that are not currently visible. 
It's not possible to kill other apps foreground processes for non-system apps. You could just open another Activity instead (eg. some information that tells the user why he can't uninstall your app).

If you have superuser access however you can kill any app. Just grab it's Process id by looping through `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`:

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : appProcesses) {
    if (PACKAGE_INSTALLER.equals(process.processName)) {
        YourFavouriteRootHelper.call("kill -9 "+process.pid);
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/omnirom/android_packages_apps_PackageInstaller/blob/android-4.4/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't help"? I assume you want to kill the uninstaller if the user tries to use it - that's just not possible (without root), the only thing you can do is to show something else over the uninstaller so the user can't use it.

Comment: i know that's not possible, i'm looking for a hack to do it, even using superuser permissions :)

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756180/ask-for-password-before-uninstalling-application is interesting for you? Especially the device admin part (more docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html )

Comment: I added a way to do it with superuser access.