# ask password on uninstalling android app?

Tags: android, security

I'm developing an app which stores info about Calls and Messages. I don't want the user to uninstall the app without entering a password. I want to prevent the user to do that. I've looked into these links too, but I couldn't get a clue:
[Ask for password before uninstalling application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756180/ask-for-password-before-uninstalling-application)

here's what I've wrote:

Android Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".DetectRemoved" >
                <intent-filter android:priority="999999">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />
                    <data android:scheme="package" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Java Code

```
 public class DetectRemoved extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES");

            if(packageNames!=null){
                for(String packageName: packageNames){
                    if(packageName!=null && packageName.equals("activity_log.pargansystem.com.activity_log")){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // start your activity here and ask the user for the password
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want the user to uninstall the app without entering a password

This is not possible. Your app will not be notified nor asked for permission for doing so.

Comment: thanks,but how to detect my app was deleted or uninstalling?possible?

Comment: Removal message is broadcasted after package is remove, so others will get the notification, byt your package is already removed at that time, so "no". See broadasts `PACKAGE_*` here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 1):

**How it Works**

In manifest.xml

add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

and broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".UninstallIntentReceiver">
  <intent-filter android:priority="0">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
  </intent-filter>
```

UninstallIntentReceiver.java (broadcast receiver class)

```
public class UninstallIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // fetching package names from extras
    String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES"); 

    if(packageNames!=null){
        for(String packageName: packageNames){
            if(packageName!=null && packageName.equals("YOUR_APPLICATION_PACKAGE_NAME")){
                // User has selected our application under the Manage Apps settings
                // now initiating background thread to watch for activity
                new ListenActivities(context).start();

            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

ListenActivities class - for monitoring the foreground activities

```
class ListenActivities extends Thread{
boolean exit = false;
ActivityManager am = null;
Context context = null;

public ListenActivities(Context con){
    context = con;
    am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
}

public void run(){

    Looper.prepare();

    while(!exit){

         // get the info from the currently running task
         List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(MAX_PRIORITY); 

         String activityName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();


         Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                 + activityName);

         if (activityName.equals("com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity")) {
            // User has clicked on the Uninstall button under the Manage Apps settings

             //do whatever pre-uninstallation task you want to perform here
             // show dialogue or start another activity or database operations etc..etc..

            // context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MyPreUninstallationMsgActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
             exit = true;
             Toast.makeText(context, "Done with preuninstallation tasks... Exiting Now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(activityName.equals("com.android.settings.ManageApplications")) {
            // back button was pressed and the user has been taken back to Manage Applications window
                      // we should close the activity monitoring now
            exit=true;
        }
    }
    Looper.loop();
}
}
```

This is the code as i found in some link Hope this helpful to you.

Comment: OK I will try again from myside.