# how to ask a password for android application while app is being uninstalled

Tags: android, android-sqlite, intentfilter

i hava a big problem that is my app is completely using Sqlite database every thing i stored in sqlite database so when ever i uninstalled my app should be ask the password then uninstalled. 
         this kind of approach is possible or not please help me Thank you.

Comment: Nope, not possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled
this might help

Answer (score 0):

Already have this question on stackoverflow. You can find out there. 
[Ask for password before uninstalling application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756180/ask-for-password-before-uninstalling-application)

Comment: Sorry bro, I have no idea about how to raise duplicate

Comment: sorry bro i didn't understood that example please explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756180/ask-for-password-before-uninstalling-application