# I want to call logout method on Android application when application is uninstalled

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, logout

I want  to call logout method on Android application when application is uninstalled.

```
 private void setlogout() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, logout,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logout successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I catch uninstall action in my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313317/can-i-catch-uninstall-action-in-my-android-app)

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/4657385